# How to pass content to RequestBody when there are a lot of parameters?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I'm using `postman` to test my requests. So I've chosen the option from postman that shows a code snippet and selected `OkHttp` and the snippet is :

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "a=foo&b=bar&c=wow&d=awesome&e=random&f=rainbows /** lots of strings **/");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
 .url(URL)
 .post(body)
 .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
 .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
 .addHeader("postman-token", "40052d2a-0ff0-ead4-1cf7-1c12f9b8eca9")
 .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

The content for the `RequestBody` is really big. I tried creating it with String concatenation and it works but what if I get a String with spaces and who knows what other edge cases exists that can mess with the content.

So is there a better way than string concatenation ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to use FormBody:

```
RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("imageUrl", imageUri.toString())
        .add("caption", caption)
        .add("foo", "bar")
        .build();
```

It also adds the content type for you and cares about encoding.

Another option would be the Uri class, but since you are already working with okhttp3, no need for it.

Comment: If I use FormBody and pass it to Request.Builder() the request I make is not correct. I think what is missing is the mediaType, cause above in the snippet I use `RequestBody.create()` before passing the body to  `Request.Builder()`

Comment: If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/FormBody.java#L29), you can see it uses the appropriate media type. What’s new with respect to your snippet is that FormBody actually encodes the string, taking care of spaces and other characters that you were worried about.

Comment: thnx it save my day

Answer (score 0):

if you have a lot of data, just using MediaType like "application/json", and Content is a Json string. First,you create a JsonObject to put data, then using toString() method to get json string
And then code like this:

```
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
RequestBody requestBody = RecordBody.create(mediaType, jsonString);
Request request = Request.Builder().url(url).post(requestBody).build();

Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
```

Hope this can help someone.